# Creating query(join) or correct the design?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am having problem with building up some simple queries with this design. The problem is simple I want get the posts with included user information, which should be all in one array so i can pass it to the express view.

Simple and for me it seems the wrong solution would be after finding all the `posts(db.post.find({email:'mo@gmail.com'})` and then looping through the posts and making one find query yo user collection and then merge the results.

Other solution would be using the DBref linking the author this may be better but i haven't found out how to make queries.

```
// User, the profile is not complete there will be more fields
var u = {
    name: 'Michael', // Is not unique
    email: 'mo@gmail.com', // Should be also unique
    fbid: '4545454asdadsa'
}

db.user.insert(u);

// User can have 0 to many posts

var p = {
    title: 'Suprise',
    body: 'Well done',
    tags: ['first', 'post', 'english'],
    author: 'mo@gmail.com',
    created: new Date(),
    modified: new Date()
};
db.post.insert(p);

var p = {
    title: 'Weather in Estonia',
    body: 'Always looks bad',
    tags: ['bad', 'weather', 'estonia'],
    author: 'mo@gmail.com',
    created: new Date(),
    modified: new Date()
}
db.post.insert(p);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var p = {
    title: 'Suprise',
    body: 'Well done',
    tags: ['first', 'post', 'english'],
    author: {
        name: 'Michael', // Is not unique
        email: 'mo@gmail.com', // Should be also unique
        fbid: '4545454asdadsa'
    },
    created: new Date(),
    modified: new Date()
};
```

You embed documents, you denormalize. This is how it works. Now you can just get all the posts and dont have to query for the users because they are already there.

### Data structure

I'll spell out how this can be done. I went completely overboard with the denormalization. This means you never need joins. Note that some of this can be removed if it's just cruft and never needed.

#### Posts collection

```
{
  title: String,
  body: String,
  tags: [String],
  author: {
    name: String,
    email: String,
    fbid: String
  },
  created: Date,
  modified: Date,
  comments: [{
    body: String,
    created: Date,
    modified: Date
  }]
}
```

#### User collection

```
{ 
  name: String,
  email: String,
  fbid: String,
  posts: [{
    title: String,
    body: String,
    tags: [String],
    created: Date,
    modified: Date,
    comments: [{
      body: String,
      created: Date,
      modified: Date
    }]
  }]
}
```

#### Comment collection

```
{
  body: String,
  created: Date,
  modified: Date,
  author: {
    name: String,
    email: String,
    fbid: String
  },
  post: {
    title: String,
    body: String,
    tags: [String],
    created: Date,
    modified: Date
    comments: [{
      body: String,
      created: Date,
      modified: Date
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: True, this might be one way. How to solve the problem when the author contains more like 7 fields, doesn't this duplicate code and make the collection size huge. Also when the author wants to change the name, this requires to change all the posts also.

Comment: @jurka yes, its called denormalization, you make the collections larger and you make query time shorter, this how you gain speed. And yes when the author changes name you have to change it everywhere, write correct code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but would the embedding document still be the best practice to use in this case when the post gets comments field and each comment got the author also. Example is here http://pastebin.com/n6eaJYGY

Comment: @jurka you can kill nesting, nested comments don't need the author field, because they are inside the post. The actual comment objects in the comments collection would need a nested author. your nested comment doesnt have to be the same as your normal comments

Comment: I have created new example based on your last post did you think something this http://pastebin.com/Cze8M4ek. But in some scenarios there is still need of join/linking is this true or is it bad design in NoSQL world? One possible way to make join type is to use some flow control methods like this in done here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839727/how-do-you-do-a-join-on-an-array-in-mongoose-mongodb-with-node-js.

Comment: @jurka the need for a manual join is bad design in the NoSQL world. The most inefficient thing your allowed to do is run a custom map reduce query over an entire collection.

Comment: @jurka Updated with a data structure for you, you never need joins. Manual joinin with control flow methods === l2nosql.